# Gradient background within a DIV has vertical tiling

Tags: css

I'm still getting my head around the use of gradients in CSS. For some reason, when I try to set a gradient background for my main div, the background appears with some odd vertical tiling. I have tried all combinations of the background-repeat property, but I cannot seem to fix this.

Here's the full code for the div, there's plenty of commented lines where I've tried different code snippets to attempt to fix this - all result in the same tiling effect:

```
#centralBox {
border: 2px solid black;
border-top: none;
border-bottom: none;
width: 980px;
height: 100%;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

/*background-color: #91C1D1;*/
/*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/


/*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #91c1d1, #91d1c1);*/
/*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #000000, #ffffff);*/
/*background: -webkit-background-size: auto;*/

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #91C1D1));

}
```

Note, I'm only using webkit until I can get the hang of the gradient properties, then I will implement other browser support.

This is how the background renders:

[image]

If I move the exact same code to a different div, the gradient renders correctly, but I (think) I need it in this div, as this is the one that houses all of my main site content.

---

Ok, the consensus seems to be that my code is ok and the fact that the rendering works when I place the code into other divs suggests there might be something else at large.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id='centralBox'>
    <div id='pageTop'>
        <div id='header'>
            ...
        </div> <!-- End of header div -->

        <div id='navigation'>
            <ul>
                <li class='inactiveLink'>Home</li>
                <li><a href='about.html'>About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href='experience.html'>Experience</a></li>
                <li><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- End of navigation div -->
    </div> <!-- End of pageTop div -->

    <div id='bodyContent'>
        ...
    </div> <!-- End of bodyContent div -->


</div> <!-- End of centralBox div -->

</body>
```

The div that I am trying to give a gradient to is centralBox - this is because it is a div that sits in the centre of my site with a fixed width and height of 100%. If I try to use a gradient on the bodyContent div, it works fine, but the bodyContent is a smaller div and so it doesn't fill the whole screen.

Comment: I think it looks fine on my side...

Comment: There is now a standard notation that works in all modern browsers. May be better start learning this, instead of the old webkit :-)

Comment: @vals I've just been teaching myself from articles and blogs that I have googled; I didn't even know all of this had been superseded! If you know of any pages or tutorials that you could link me to for the new notation, I would be really appreciative!

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients

Comment: @vals, thanks for this. I wish I'd found this first, it's probably the best written tutorial I've seen!

Comment: Just in case anyone is still reading this thread, this graphical glitch only seems to happen on Safari. I'll keep trying to figure it out but for now will leave the gradient out!

Answer (score 0):

[W3schools]
CSS3 defines two types of gradients:

```
Linear Gradients (goes down/up/left/right/diagonally)
```

Have you tried a linear graident from left to right? is what you are trying to achieve?

Example:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red , blue);
```

In fact your's looks fine, having had a second look... just depends which way you are trying to get the effect I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried multiple directions, linear and circular gradients. They always generate this three-tiered effect. As I have noted in other comments, using the code in different divs does not produce this effect, so there's obviously something about the particular div that I'm trying to give a gradient to.

Comment: I've been plugging away at this and the problem only seems to crop up in Safari 7.0.3. For now I've just removed the gradient, perhaps I'll put it back in the future!

Answer (score 0):

When I first started with CSS3 Gradients I found this site to be a massive help. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ Not only is it an amazing time saver it is virtually compatible with every browser.

Also, your code looks fine on my side aswell. Are you using a webkit browser?

Comment: @Matthew, I am using Safari 7.0.3 - that is webkit right? The code snippet seems to work when I paste it into different divs, there's obviously something about the div I'm trying to use it in that is having a clash...